# Different composition of a number using small numbers

Tags: c++

This is problem from GeeksforGeeks.

You can win three kinds of basketball points, 1 point, 2 points, and 3 points. Given a total score n, print out all the combination to compose n. I have implemented the following solution. But I am getting some values print multiple times. like for 2, I am getting

```
2
1 1
2
1 1
```

I am not able to find out where its going wrong.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

void print(vector<int>& A){
    for(int i=0;i<A.size();i++)
        cout<<A[i]<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
}

void fun(int x,int m,vector<int>& A){
    for(int i=m;i>0;i--){
        if(x-i==0){
            A.push_back(i);
            print(A);
            A.pop_back();
        }
        else if(x-i>0){
            A.push_back(i);
            fun(x-i,i,A);
            A.pop_back();
        }
        else{
            fun(x,i,A);
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    vector<int> A;
    fun(n,3,A);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has one call in excess... in particular the part

```
...
else {
    fun(x,i,A);
}
```

doesn't make sense.

You need to recurse only if the number of points you're subtracting is not getting past or to the total. You're handling correctly the two cases `(x-i==0)` and `(x-i>0)`, but for `(x-i<0)` you must do nothing.